# Meaning and concept of word "intuitive " in applied sciences and engineering?

Tags: word-usage, terminology, usage

Google returns meaning of intuitive as

> using or based on what one feels to be true even without conscious reasoning.

But in context of applied sciences and engineering, this meaning doesn't makes much sense.

For example,

> An intuitive understanding of the Fourier transform.

Fourier transform is a mathematical concept, so how is it compatible with last part of meaning given by Google "*without the need for conscious reasoning*"?

Comment: Google may be responsible for a good many things, but stating “Google returns” is useless information in relation to questions on this site? If you wish to base a question on a definition, you need to state the original source and why you consider this authoritative (as you presumably do). Again, why do you think the author of your second quotation is using the word correctly? You need to research different dictionaries or etymology sites that give the history and sourced examples of usage instead of posting draw horses.

Comment: It's possible to understand a mathematical concept without conscious reasoning. Do you need to get a calculator out to know what 2+2 is?

Comment: Also, there are at least 3 math forums on SE.

Comment: Question is about word meaning in scientific (including mathematical) context. The number of math fora has little relevance to anything.  Also, what the heck does 'posting draw horses' even mean?  @DSPCS consider, perhaps  'counterintuitive' science such as the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), or [Braes's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braess%27s_paradox).  Without conscious reasoning, given you have a 1 in 365 chance of sharing a birthday with a random stranger, you intuit it would take more than 23 people to have >50% chance of a shared birthday.